# script file to check java

Tags: java, linux, shell

I have a script file which looks like below:

```
    # /bin/sh

if [ -z "$JAVACMD" ] ; then
   if [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ] ; then
      JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
   else
      JAVACMD="`which java`"
   fi
 fi

if [ ! -x "$JAVACMD" ] ; then
 echo "Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly; cannot execute: $JAVACMD"
 exit 1
fi
```

Can somebody please tell me what does "if" condition checks for exactly ? I can guess that the script checks for java installed on the system but curious to know what does it do exactly.

Comment: Do your research before posting a question on SO. There are plenty of [tutorials](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html) online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first if statement tests to see if the `$JAVACMD` variable has been set. If not then it sets it, constructing it from `$JAVA_HOME` if that is set or trying to find any `java` executable if not.

The final if statement checks whether the path that `$JAVACMD` points to actually exists and reports an error if not.

Answer (score 2):

- `-z` checks if the string has a **z**ero length (ie is empty)
- `-n` checks if the string has a **n**on-zero length
- `-x` checks if the file e**x**ists is has executable permissions

See the [`test` manual pages](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?test) for the other available flags